# How to block a referrer's full URL and not only the domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm getting DDoS'd by slowhttptest. All of the entries in my `access.log` file have the referring URL as `http://code.google.com/p/slowhttptest/`. I want to set up my .htaccess to block visitors with that URL as their HTTP_REFERER. Everything I can find is how to block an entire domain, but I want to block this specific URL. The code below is to block a domain, but will it work with `code\.google\.com/p/slowhttptest` in the RewriteCond?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `example\.com` with `/p/slowhttptest/`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /p/slowhttptest/ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```